# jqGrid make edittype select fit column width

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid, which contains a lot of select-editors. When a row goes into edit mode, the selects are longer than the acutal column. Is it possible to make the grid autosize the selects, so that the user can see (directly) that it is a select?

This is how it looks like when edit mode is entered:

[image]

And it looks like this, when dropped down (I have masked a few items in the image):

[image]

And this is what I would like (except ofcourse that the column should not be resized, but the select instead):

[image]

**EDIT:**
I partially solved it, by setting editOptions, style: "width: X0px" for each select in the colModel. It not perfect, but good enough for now.

Comment: Which web browser you used? Do you tried to use [multiselect widget](https://github.com/ehynds/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget) von Eric Hynds used in [singe select mode](http://www.erichynds.com/examples/jquery-ui-multiselect-widget/demos/#single)?

Comment: Using IE9. I'll look into Eric Hynds widget.